# Reading bytes for an image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, byte, python-imaging-library

I read 784 bytes (a 28x28 image) from a file:

```
with open(self.filePath, 'rb') as f:
    aLetter = f.read(784)
    print ('A Letter',aLetter)
    image = Image.frombytes('1',[79,78],aLetter)
```

When I print and throw that 'letter' into text pad, I count 764 bytes, not 784.   but then when I pass letter to pillow in frombytes, I can pass it up to a size `[79,78]` byte array.

What gives? How many bytes do I have?  How do I get my 784 bytes array to create a 28x28 letter image? and how is Pillow seeing more bytes than are there?

For those interested the data is from here:
http://cis.jhu.edu/~sachin/digit/digit.html

Which explains:

> Each training example is of size 28x28 pixels. The pixels are stored as unsigned chars (1 byte) and take values from 0 to 255

Comment: If `len(aLetter)` really is only 764 bytes, then trying to create a 79 by 78 size image will fail with a `ValueError: not enough image data` exception.

Comment: If an image is created, you had the right number of bytes. Try `len(aLetter)`, don't print the binary object and count manually..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have 764 bytes, because an exception is thrown if you are that much short:

```
>>> Image.frombytes('1', [79, 78], bytes(764))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2331, in frombytes
    im.frombytes(data, decoder_name, args)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 786, in frombytes
    raise ValueError("not enough image data")
ValueError: not enough image data
```

while you can make a too-large image with 784 bytes:

```
>>> Image.frombytes('1', [79, 78], bytes(784))
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=1 size=79x78 at 0x104D2ACF8>
```

The minimum number of bytes PIL accepts for a 79 x 78 image is 780 bytes. Because you are creating a `'1'` mode image, you get 8 pixels out of every byte, so you only need `math.ceil(79 / 8)`, or 10 bytes per row.

To look at the length of a `bytes` object, print the `len()` function result:

```
>>> with open('data0', 'rb') as f:
...     letter_data = f.read(28 * 28)
...     print(len(letter_data))
...
784
```

You are using the wrong mode for the data however. `'1'` is a *on or off* image format, only 0 or 1 have meaning. The image training data uses a full byte, or 256 possible values, per pixel, so you want to load this with the `'L'` mode:

```
letter_image = Image.frombytes('L', (28, 28), letter_data)
```

When using `'L'`, the full 256 possible values of each byte are used, and you must pass in 28 * 28 bytes, or get an error if you really only had 764 bytes:

```
>>> image = Image.frombytes('L', (28, 28), letter_data[:764])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2331, in frombytes
    im.frombytes(data, decoder_name, args)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 786, in frombytes
    raise ValueError("not enough image data")
ValueError: not enough image data
```

Using `letter_image.save('/tmp/0.png')`, the first image from `data0` is exported as a PNG image and looks like this:

[image: First training image from data0, a white circle on black]

Comment: Thanks again Martijn.  If this were real code, would you leave it as f.read(28 * 28)? It seems clearer to me.

Comment: I’d move the value to a constant but use `28 * 28`; Python optimises literal arithmetic at compile time and stores the result of the multiplication.